# In vim, can I combine ":w" and running current script together?

Tags: vim

Every time I edit my python script, I have to type `:w` and then `:!./myscript.py` (run current script).

Can I combine those two commands together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write this in your `.vimrc`:

```
function! SaveAndRun()
    w
    !%:p
endfunction

nmap <F2> :call SaveAndRun()<cr>
```

and it will execute the current file when you press f2 in normal mode.

Answer (score 5):

Define a function in your `.vimrc` and then define a command to invoke it.

```
function DoMyStuff()
    :w
    :!./myscript.py
endfunction

command W exec DoMyStuff()
```

Then, you can call it with `:W`.

If I am interpret the title of your question literally, and you just want to execute the last executed command, you can use `!!` in command mode to execute the last external command. Combined with the pipe, this looks like the following.

```
:w | !!
```

Comment: I would say you should make it a command since it is already an uppercase letter.

Comment: No I mean an ex command (`:h command`) the cmap makes it really hard (to almost impossible) to type a literal W.

Comment: @FDinoff, Thank you for pointing that out. I checked the help, and then tested and updated.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can using a pipe character between the commands:

> :w | !./myscript.py